# problem mount cdrom under Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mount, vmware, dvd

I have just installed VMWare 10 on my Dell PC, and installed Ubuntu 14.04. Now I am having trouble mount `/cdrom`.  Here's what I have tried:

```
mkdir /mnt/cdrom
mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

Actually, I do have a cd in the cdrom, and Window 8 was able to read document out of this CD.  I need advice on how to resolve this error. I am a newbie here.  thanks!

Comment: What's the output of `ls  /dev/sr*`. Try to mount after reboot, without launching vmware.

Comment: @André Marinho why no response? See above comment.

Comment: The output is /dev/sr0

Comment: @AndréMarinho please see if this helps https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_disk_add_cd_dvd.html

Comment: What trouble do you have? I just did your commands on LinuxMint 17 just fine. Notice, you need to run `mkdir /mnt/cdrom` as root, i.e., `sudo mkdir /mnt/cdrom`

Answer (score 4):

Install VMware tools using the open-vm-tools package.

```
apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

Any other driver install is legacy officially.

Answer (score 2):

- Ubuntu as Guest OS in VMWare on Windows 8 host.
- Host has access to CDROM, but not guest OS.

  Check VMWare settings... there must be something either locking out - or not enabling - CDROM access for the guest OS.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like your drive is not connected to the VM. To connect the drive the follow the steps below.
[image: go to vm settings]
[image: configure how you the cd drive to be connected]

If this is not what you're looking for, please add more details to your question.

Comment: I got this: devfsadm: command not found

Comment: @AndréMarinho I really got confused in the first place, I now edited the answer.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov And in ubuntu server, how to mount it?!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a CentOS 5.11 VM. The VM had the CD-ROM enabled, and also enabled on boot yet I got the "no medium found" error. The fix was to disable the CD-ROM on the VM, click "OK", let the machine reconfigure, then re-enable the CD-ROM, click "OK" again, and let the machine reconfigure again.

I suspect that the OS had "ejected" the CD at some point and this IT Crowd style solution ("Turn it off and back on again") reset that state.